# What does the following mean translated to English from mathematical language?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What does this mean in English language translated from mathematical text?

$$S=\left\{ \frac{1}{z} \mid z\in R\right\}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please edit your question and replace the image with the code S=\{\frac{1}{z}\;|\;z\in\mathbb{R}\} between dollars. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Fair question from a NEW contributor... Why downvotes? Why closing?

Comment: Stricto sensu this is undefined, as the inverse of $0$ is undefined.

Comment: $S=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, that means that $S$ is the set of all non-zero real numbers, in plain English.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have chosen "complex analysis" as a tag I guess that here we should see $z$ as a complex number (although this is not explicitly written).

Having said that, I guess that  $S=\{\frac{1}{z}\;|\;z\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is the set of all the complex numbers $1/z$ such that $z$ is real number, that is the imaginary part of the complex number $z$ is zero.

In order to find a simpler description of the elements of the set $S$, note that, when $z\not=0$, if the imaginary part of $z$ is zero then also imaginary part of $1/z$ is zero. Why? Is the converse true?

Comment: How did you read complex numbers into the set? It is the set of all real numbers 1/z, given z $\in \mathbb R$ or simply, the set of of non-zero real numbers.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost The proposer choose "complex analysis" as a tag (see below the question). This is not explicitly said in the question, but it is plausible otherwise the exercise is quite trivial.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I hope that the proposer will clear up this mistery.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost I edited my answer. I am not going to write the full answer. The downvote is fine. But if you ask for an explanation, please wait for it and then downvote...

Comment: Even if we assume the set $S \subseteq \mathbb C$, the way you have defined it is not consistent, since $z\neq 0$. Put this somewhere in your answer: The set of non-zero complex numbers $(a+bi)(b=0 \land a\neq 0)$. I upvoted it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For all real numbers $z$ we compute the number $\frac{1}{z}$, whenever possible (so when $z \neq 0$) and put all these (and only these) in the set $S$. Note that the reciprocal of a real is also real, and every non-zero real can be written this way so $S$ is really the set of all nonzero real numbers, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, written in a weird way.

Comment: This is the best answer. The others lack colloquiality in translation: the set of non-zero real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard set notation. In English it is read as "The set of numbers $\frac{1}{z}$ such that $z$ is a real number".